# Converting 3.3V signal to 5V with tri-state

Tags: buffer, tri-state

I need to buffer and tri-state a 3.3V 8 bit signal, and shift the output to 5V (when the buffer is not in tri-state).

I am using a [CD54HC373](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/scls452a/scls452a.pdf) buffer and 2 [BOB-12009](https://www.mouser.it/ProductDetail/SparkFun/BOB-12009?qs=WyAARYrbSnb%252bGYLWggQnjQ==&gclid=CjwKCAiA_ZTfBRBjEiwAN6YG4dkFdbL5QoidFVEu2A3X1Od4tPo7yZmGvNc2RZQtcBAv5PDQ_KxWyRoC9QMQAvD_BwE) logic level converters, but I can't find a way to output a 5V signal.

I have tried to route the signal in 2 ways:

- [3v output from the board] -> 2 [BOB-12009] - > [CD54HC373].
  In this way, I can enable/disable the tri-state of the output using the OE pin of the CD54HC373, but i get a 3.3v output (I need a 5v one).
- [3v output from the board]-> [CD54HC373] -> 2 [BOB-12009]. Tri-stating using OE does not work anymore, because of the logic converters.

I am powering the CD54HC373 using a 5v input!

Any advice?

Comment: Just use a 74HCT373 (or 54HCT373).  The HCT parts are designed to be CMOS levels out and TTL levels in -- and the TTL levels are pretty close to 3.3V CMOS.  That's basically the level-conversion technology of choice for the 1990's, when things started moving to 3.3V but there was still a lot of 5V stuff around.  (Hmm.  I just reviewed this and decided to make it an answer.  Stand by).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a 74HCT373 (or 54HCT373).  The HCT parts are designed to be CMOS levels out and TTL levels in -- and the TTL levels are pretty close to 3.3V CMOS.  That's basically the level-conversion technology of choice for the 1990's, when things started moving to 3.3V but there was still a lot of 5V stuff around.

Comment: ok, will try with an HCT and let you know. Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks for getting back with the update!  It's nice to know when I've helped.

Comment: @elder0010 - It's good news that your problem is solved with a 74HCT373. As Tim explained, the 74HCT series have CMOS outputs - effectively they have the same output design as 74HC (or 54HC) series devices. It's just the input side of 74HCT devices which is designed with different, TTL-compatible, threshold voltages. *However* this successful result for you with the 74HCT373 (which I expect means 5V output levels that you wanted) *doesn't* explain why the outputs of your 54HC373 were only 3.3V. Remember, the output of xxHC and xxHCT are the same, so output voltages should have been the same!

Answer (score 2):

The cheapest way is probably with the HCT373 as @TimWescott suggests, but you can also consider a [NLSV8T244](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NLSV8T244-D.PDF) which has two supply rails and will not load the 3.3V inputs if the 5V supply is not high.

There are more common bidirectional 8-bit parts such as [this](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC4245A.pdf) and [this](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74LVC_LVCH8T245.pdf) with similar features.

The above-linked 74LVCH8T245B is about $1 one-off and can convert bidirectionally over a wide range (1.2V to 5.5V rails) with high speed, so it's a good tool to have in the box.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the CD54HC373 datasheet I would think your first method should work:

```
[3v output from the board] -> 2 [BOB-12009] - > [CD54HC373].
```

You are connecting VCC to 5V?  How are you measuring that it's outputing 3.3v? multimeter with no load?  The /OE pin is active low, so make sure to ground it if you want to see the 5v output, and put some data data into the chip (bring LE and D signals high)

If that setup isn't working I would assume the part is bad.

Comment: Yes, i am powering it using a 5V source. I am measuring it using a multimeter. It should output the same power as VCC i'm right?